# Compare each item in a list with all previous items, print only unique items

Tags: regex, python-3.x, comparison

I am using the following regexp to match all occurrences of a special kind of number:

```
^([0-57-9]|E)[12][0-9]{3}[A-Z]?[A-Z]([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{4})
```

Let's assume that this regex matches the following five numbers:

```
31971R0974
11957E075
31971R0974-A01P2
31971R0974-A05
51992PC0405
```

These matches are then printed using the following code. This prints each item in the list and if the item contains a dash, everything after the dash is discarded.

```
def number_function():

    for x in range(0, 10):

    print("Number", number_variable[x].split('-', 1)[0])
```

However, this would print five lines where lines 1, 3 and 4 would be the same.

I need your help to write a script which compares each item with all previous items and only prints the item if it does not already exist.

So, the desired output would be the following three lines:

```
31971R0974
11957E075
51992PC0405
```

EDIT 2:

I solved it! I just needed to do some moving around. Here's the finished product:

```
def instrument_function():
    desired = set()

    for x in range(0, 50):
        try:
            instruments_celex[x]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            before_dash = instruments_celex[x].split('-', 1)[0]
            desired.add(before_dash)        

    for x in desired:
        print("Cited instrument", x)
```

Comment: Is the order of items relevant?

Comment: @Tim: No, the order of the items is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done practically no python up until now, but this might do what you're after

```
def number_function():
    desired = set()
    for x in range(0, 10):
        before_hyphen = number_variable[x].split('-', 1)[0]
        desired.add(before_hyphen)
    for x in desired:
        print("Number", x)
```

Comment: A range variable instead of looping over the list? -1

Comment: What @LennartRegebro is referring to is using `range` in the for loop when the correct way to write it in Python is `for x in number_variable:` with `before_hyphen = x.split(..)` in the body of the loop.

Comment: I simply used the askers example directly, how was I to know the asker might want every item instead of just the first 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your "finished" function that is more reaonable.

```
# Don't use instruments_celex as a global variable, that's terrible. 
# Pass it in to the function instead:
def instrument_function(instruments_celex): 
    unique = set()
    # In Python you don't need an integer loop variable. This is not Java.
    # Just loop over the list:
    for entry in instruments_celex:
       unique.add(entry.split('-', 1)[0])

    for entry in unique:
        print("Cited instrument", entry)
```

You can also make use of generator expressions to make this shorter:

```
def instrument_function(instruments_celex): 
    unique = set(entry.split('-', 1)[0] for entry in instruments_celex)
    for entry in set:
       print("Cited instrument", entry)
```

That's it. It's so simple in fact that I wouldn't make a separate function of it unless I do it at least two times in the program.

Comment: Nitpicks: you probably want `for entry in unique`, and what you are calling a "list comprehension" is actually a generator expression.

Comment: @dbaupp: The first wasn't a nitpick, thanks. And yes, you are correct, it's a generator expression. That is a  nitpick, but I'll change it anyway. Always better to be exact. :-)